# UWP - BackgroundTask and ContactManager

Tags: background, uwp, contacts

I am facing the problem that if I try to access the ContactManager from a BackgroundTask I get a System.IO.FileLoadException .

The same code works well when calling it from my main application:

```
    public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        test();
        deferral.Complete();

    }

    private async void test()
    {
        ContactStore contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();
    }
```

The BackgroundTasks starts normally, but as soon as I call "test" the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your async void test to async Task test

Comment: still the same problem:
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime

The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

Comment: can you share a repro project? it works fine for me. Did you also put await infront of the call to test?

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it...

Reason was that I switched to VS2017 while developing and got a wrong dependency in the project.json of the backgroundtask:

While the main project had:

`"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.0.0"
  },`

the background task got:

`"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.2.2"
  },`

after editing to 5.0.0 all went perfect

Comment: The dependency is not wrong actually, you should update both to the latest (5.3.1) if possible. Except bugfixes you'll get new APIs available.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I am now uninstalling VS2015 to install 2017 one so I can't test by my own but some of APIs are not available in Background Tasks so test the method I will mention :

1- Create a new Solution with type Class Library .

2- Put methods you want there .

3- Make the class library a reference for your background task solution .

3- Call your methods in this way `classLib.className.FuncName();`

4- See if it work or not.